# another word for an effortless look as it relates to fashion

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word for, just a little undone, as it relates to fashion. For example, you always look very put together but never seems like you've tried that hard and never look too perfect. As if you are done yet undone in some way and can't pinpoint how but the look is envied.

> She was admired by everyone for how she looked,_______, like she didn't even try but was styled impeccably.
>
> Her look was so ____, like she didn't care to look perfect but somehow still did.

Comment: Like "effortless" beauty?

Comment: yes! but is there a less common word or more interesting word for that? i'm trying to come up with a name for a fashion company

Comment: Listen, with the SWR tag you _must specify how the word is to be used_ with a sample sentence.

Comment: She was admired by everyone for how she looked,_______, like she didn't even try but was styled impeccably.

Comment: She had this ____ way about her, she was dressed beautifully and it seemed so effortless.

Comment: The adjective *elegant* or the nouns *elegance*, *grace*, or  *style* would be appropriate.

Comment: That idea reminds me of how the painting crew at the College of William & Mary was tasked, in preparation for a 1981 visit by Prince Charles, to repaint all the fences on campus but **without making them look as if they’d been freshly painted**!  They eventually decided to paint the fences & then immediately “freshen-up” the new paint with whitewash. I certainly wouldn’t recommend “Whitewash” as a name for a fashion brand, but with the idea of “freshen” in mind, maybe “Freshen-Easy Fashions [for that 'freshened-easy look']” could work (& maybe even withstand claims of trade mark infringement).

Comment: You could consider "natural", or one of its synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

I am taking [C. Z. Guest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._Z._Guest) as the personification of the quality the OP is describing.  In a comment, the OP said he wanted a word for a fashion company.   ***Instinctive*** would fit, and  *Instinctive by Skoon* has a ring to it. **Instinctive**, defined by [Macmilan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/instinctive)

> done without thinking, because of a natural tendency or ability

In the OP's sentence:

Her look was so *instinctive*, like she didn't care to look perfect but somehow still did

See [C. Z. Guest, Photos](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cz+guest+photos); Photo below by Slim Aarons; Book by [Susanna Salk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0847839710)

Just look at C.Z. Guest. She is not wearing shoes, her shorts are wrinkled, her only adornment is a narrow pink belt, but she could not be more perfect. She may have put a great deal of thought into that outfit and to her more formal clothes, but the effect was of instinctive ease and elegance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Granted, it would sound a bit redundant in your second example sentence, but I think [**carefree**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/carefree) would work well overall, including in your first example:

> She was admired by everyone for how she looked, **carefree**, like she
>   didn't even try but was styled impeccably.

---

> **carefree**
>     adjective
>
> 1. without anxiety or worry.
> 2. requiring little care : carefree fabrics.
>
> (from *Dictionary.com*)

As for its use as a name for a fashion brand, be careful, though, for [“Carefree Fashions {of Scottsdale, Arizona}](https://www.etsy.com/listing/459862352/vintage-carefree-fashions-of-scottsdale)” might already exist (from *etsy.com*) and it could possibly risk confusion with “wash and wear"/"wrinkle free” fabrics.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the word you need is **insouciance**.  [Merriam-Webster says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insouciance) it means *lighthearted unconcern* and is synonymous with **nonchalance**.

> She was admired by everyone for how she looked, **insouciant**, like she didn't even try but was styled impeccably.

Incidentally, back in the 1640s when I was but a wee lad, Robert Herrick captured the sentiment you're describing in his poem [Delight in Disorder](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/47285#poem). The poem ends:

> A careless shoe-string, in whose tie
>   I see a wild civility:
>   Do more bewitch me, than when art
>   Is too precise in every part.

*Wild civility* is a magnificent oxymoron, and you could do worse than to choose that as the name of your firm.

Answer (score 1):

I think "**natural**" fits your description best. It's a humble word, but all beauty in nature is arrayed in that way.

> She was admired by everyone for how she looked, **natural**, like she
>   didn't even try but was styled impeccably.
>
> Her look was so **natural**, like she didn't care to look perfect but
>   somehow still did.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/natural

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no-one has proposed what I'd say is the "industry standard" term in the fashion world...

> **casual**  - selected definitions from the full [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28629?redirectedFrom=casual#eid)
>    3: *Occurring or brought about without design or premeditation*
>    *-- coming up or presenting itself ‘as it chances’*
>     6b: *Showing (real or assumed) unconcern or lack of interest*

...in support of which I would cite Google Books claimed 80,400 results for [***casual dress***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22casual+dress%22)

I assume everyone would agree *without design or premeditation* implies *without making any effort.*